# Need background image to scroll but conflicts with fixed left column and liquid right column

Tags: css, background-image, css-position, liquid-layout

here is the layout

http://timsegreto.com/cssmock/mock.html

i need the background image to scroll concordant with the text block in the right column.
ive tried many different ways with no success.
any ideas would greatly appreciated.
not sure if its possible or what t research to make it work.

thanks!

Comment: This works in FF and Chrome but completely wrecks the layout in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have fixed positioning on the wrong element. Try making #framecontent position fixed and remove it from #maincontent.

**EDIT** It's 'quirks' mode that's causing you IE issues. Get rid of the:

```
<!--Force IE6 into quirks mode with this comment tag-->
```

from the beginning of your html. I'm sure this is supposed to be solving other cross-browser issues but it's ruining fixed positioning.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I tried that and it works perfect in FF and Chrome but wrecks the layout in IE. any ideas? i've uploaded the version with your suggestion. http://timsegreto.com/cssmock/mock.html

Comment: @robotmahn: Try removing the overflow property on #mainconent.

Comment: This is pretty great, I just found out that IE no longer supports fixed positioning. I'm looking into this. In the meantime, get rid of all of those overflow properties.

Answer (score 0):

Have you adding an extra div and setting the background image on that instead of on the body? You could absolutely position this extra div in the body with top: 0 - it would scroll with the page then...

not sure if thats what you're looking for exactly...

Comment: That does work in FF and Chrome but wrecks the layout in IE. It pushes the text area way down, and moves the left column off the left side of the page. Here is the page with your suggestion. http://timsegreto.com/cssmock/mockb.html any ideas for a hack?